# How do you redirect a friendly url to a dynamic url?

Tags: php, redirect, query-string

What is the best way to dynamically redirect a friendly looking url on Linux to dynamic on Windows?

ex.
domainone.com/dir/one/two
redirects to
domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=one&b=two

and

domainone.com/dir/three/four
redirects to
domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=three&b=four

Comment: Why are both Windows and Linux involved in this - is there a Linux machine serving as proxy to Windows machine?

Comment: Do you want a proper redirect, ie. the browser URL changes, or were you hoping for it to be transparent?

Comment: @Ben The Linux hosting is mine, the Windows is a partner's site.

Comment: @Orbling Yes, proper redirect.

Comment: The redirect needs to be on the Linux side.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP header called [Location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) is how you redirect a user across hosts/domains.

Depending on your server configuration and the mechanism used to generate the HTTP headers, the specific implementation will vary. An example in PHP (as your question appears to be tagged) is to include the following code:

```
header('Location: http://domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=one&b=two');
```

The string above is like any other string, so apply the appropriate logic to provide the desired redirection URL.

The same effect is also possible in the domain configuration files (the precise path differs across server software and operating system) or more conventionally in `.htaccess` files. If you provide more information about your hosting environment, someone will be able to help you devise the rewrite rule you need. I prefer to put this level of smart rewriting in a PHP script, since I think .htaccess files tend to be harder to manage and "read".

Comment: How do I make it pull the ?a=one&b=two from .com/one/two?

Comment: [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) has your usual string manipulation library, and you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the requested path. How to perform basic string manipulation is beyond the scope of this question; besides, plenty of [websites](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_string.asp) out there can do a much better job than I can of introducing you to how to get information out of strings in PHP.

Comment: I'm sorry that is what the question is, how should I reword?

Comment: @Nate, you can use a similar regex to the ones for Apache in PHP if you wish to go that route.  `$redirectURI = 'http://domaintwo.com/index.aspx?' . preg_replace("#^/a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "a=$1&b=$2"); header('Location: ' . $redirectURI); exit();`

Comment: @Orbling: while the regex solution works, and is probably the fastest way to do it (it's likely how I would do it), if Nate is just getting started with coding, beginning with basic string manipulation might be a better dip in rather than a regular expression. Also, I'm like 90% sure that you need to escape your forward slashes, delimit the regex with forward slashes, and switch the second and third arguments.

Comment: @Steven Agreed on the use of regex, I'll show an example without momentarily.  The slashes do not need escaping, I used #-marks instead as the delimiters, you can use any character and should not use the default / when playing with URLs/paths as it gets in the way with all the escaping.

Comment: `$uriParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); $bPart = array_pop($uriParts); $aPart = array_pop($uriParts); $redirectURI = 'http://domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=' . $aPart . '&b=' . $bPart;`  Without the regex it does become tricky to *match* the URL, ie. know that you need to substitute.

Comment: @Orbling: Thanks for clarifying that for me. I never knew that about PHP before; I haven't visited the `preg_` docs in ages, so I guess that'll show me. I'm definitely going to begin delimiting my regular expressions with something other than `/` from now on. Although I'll miss `/http:\/\//`.

Comment: @Steven Aye, the leaning toothpicks are hard to loose.  So many people do not understand regexp, I wonder how many think the `\/\/` in that is some mystic code for `www`. ;-)  (BTW, it's a general feature of perl-regexp (preg), as opposed to PHP specific.  I still use slash as my standard delimiter, just not when I need to use it within the pattern.)

Answer (score 2):

**From within Apache:**

Either in a server configuration file, or more likely in an `.htaccess` file.

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this, but as you want a redirect, it would be more appropriate to use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) and the RedirectMatch statement.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=$1&b=$2
```

Rewrite variant:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ http://domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=$1&b=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Note the use of **301**, that is a permanent redirect, use **302** for temporary, or when you always want people to redirect rather than going directly on future accesses.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty standard way to approach this on Linux is to use Apache with mod_rewrite (how to install and configure Apache and mod_rewrite, if it's not already set up, will depend on your Linux distribution)

Then, in your Apache configuration, you can add a line like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/a/([^/]+)/([^/]+) http://www.domaintwo.com/index.aspx?a=$1&b=$2
```